# SQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, psql

I want to get a list of tables in ma database to String. I have connect with database, but when I try use Postgres "\dt" function, getTables() throws `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\".`
What is the problem? A simple backslash is reported as an error by 
JDK (treats `\dt` as regex).

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataConnect {
    Statement statement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    DataConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "", "");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.append("Driver is missing");
            end();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.append("Wrong order");
            end();
        }
    }
    ArrayList<String> getTables() {
        ArrayList tables = new ArrayList();
        try {
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("\\dt");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String databaseName = rs.getString("Name");
            }
            return tables;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            end();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course user and password i remove only to publish on stack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\dt` isn't valid SQL syntax - it's a [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) [meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS). You can perform a similar functionality by querying the information schema:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables");
```

Comment: `psql` documentation calls them [Meta-Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

Comment: @Andreas I thought "macro" sounded odd, but couldn't remember the right name. Thanks! Edited that in to my answer.